# From completeness of matrix rep to that of character

Tags: representation-theory

I am learning representation theory and trying to understand how to prove the completeness relation of characters.

For matrix representations, we have

$$\sum_{\mu,l,k} \frac{n_\mu}{n_G}D^\mu(g)^l_{\ k} D^\dagger_\nu(g')^k_{\ l}=\delta_{gg'}$$
where $n_G$ is the order of the group, $n_\mu$ is the dimension of the irreducible representation, and $D^\dagger_\nu(g)^k_{\ l}=[D^\nu (g)^l_{\ k}]^*$

If we want to set up the corresponding completeness relation for characters, we sum over $g$ in the class $\zeta_i$, and $g'$ in the class $\zeta_j$, to get

$$\sum_{g\in\zeta_i,g'\in\zeta_j}\sum_{\mu,l,k} \frac{n_\mu}{n_G}D^\mu(g)^l_{\ k} D^\dagger_\nu(g')^k_{\ l}=\sum_{g\in\zeta_i,g'\in\zeta_j}\delta_{gg'}$$
The right-hand side will be simply $n_i\delta _{ij}$ and the left-hand side will be
$$\frac{n_in_j}{n_G}\sum_{\mu}\chi_\mu^{\dagger i}\chi_i^\nu\mathrm{Tr}E/n_\mu=\frac{n_in_j}{n_G}\sum_{\mu}\sum_{\mu}\chi_\mu^{\dagger i}\chi_i^\nu$$
where $n_{i,j}$ is the number of elements in the class $\zeta_{i,j}$, and $\chi^\nu_i=\mathrm{Tr}(D^\mu (g))$ for $g\in\zeta_i$ is the character of the $\nu$-representation for class $\zeta_i$

It says in the book that the simplification of the left-hand side is done by this lemma
$$\sum_{g\in\zeta_{i}}U^\mu(g)=\frac{n_i}{n_\mu}\chi_i^\mu E$$
which $U$ is an irreducible representation. This is literally an application of Schur's lemma and I have no problem in understanding this lemma.

But when I try to apply this lemma to the left-hand side,

$$\sum_{g\in\zeta_i,g'\in\zeta_j}\sum_{\mu,l,k} \frac{n_\mu}{n_G}D^\mu(g)^l_{\ k} D^\dagger_\nu(g')^k_{\ l}$$

I get confused about how it works because this lemma tells me

$$\sum_{g\in\zeta_i,l,k} D^\mu(g)^l_{\ k}=\frac{n_i}{n_\mu}\chi_i^\mu n_\mu$$
but I am not sure how it transforms

$$\sum_{g\in\zeta_i,g'\in\zeta_j}\sum_{\mu,l,k} \frac{n_\mu}{n_G}D^\mu(g)^l_{\ k} D^\dagger_\nu(g')^k_{\ l}$$ into
$$\frac{n_in_j}{n_G}\sum_{\mu}\chi_\mu^{\dagger i}\chi_i^\nu\mathrm{Tr}E/n_\mu$$
since when we sum up $g,l,k$, we also have dependence on $D_\nu^\dagger(g')^k_l$ which is not a common factor to pull out.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out myself, the key step is to sum over $k$ first to get the diagonal of the product. Then we just rearrange things and apply the lemma.
Red equal sign: sum over $k$ to get the $(l,l)$ component of the product matrix $D^\mu(g)D^\dagger_\mu(g')$. Blue: sum over $l$ to get the trace. Light green: Use linearity to bring the summation over $g$ inside the trace. Yellow: Use the lemma. Dark green: Use linearity again to bring the summation over $g'$ inside the trace. Gray: Use the lemma again.
[image]